# Categorical (string) features in sklearn for 10cv SVM regression

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm

I have a mix of different types of features in a csv files (categorical strings, 0-1 binary, floats). I want to do a SVM regression with 10 fold cross validation. Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40617862/how-to-encode-categorical-features-in-sklearn), I tried the following to read in the data, but I get an error that string cannot be converted to float:

```
df = pd.read_csv("output.csv")
datanumpy = df.as_matrix()
x = datanumpy[:, 0:143]  # select columns 1 through 41 (the features)
y = datanumpy[:, 144]  # select column 42 (the labels)


clf = SVC(kernel='linear')

clf.fit(x, y)
```

Any idea how I can handle those factors?

The error message is:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-731136d5a713> in <module>()
     75 
     76 # # fitting x samples and y classes
---> 77 clf.fit(x, y)
     78 
     79 

/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/svm/base.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    149         self._sparse = sparse and not callable(self.kernel)
    150 
--> 151         X, y = check_X_y(X, y, dtype=np.float64, order='C', accept_sparse='csr')
    152         y = self._validate_targets(y)
    153 

/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_X_y(X, y, accept_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, multi_output, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, y_numeric, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    519     X = check_array(X, accept_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite,
    520                     ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples,
--> 521                     ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    522     if multi_output:
    523         y = check_array(y, 'csr', force_all_finite=True, ensure_2d=False,

/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    380                                       force_all_finite)
    381     else:
--> 382         array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)
    383 
    384         if ensure_2d:

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '/Users/dorien/AC/Projects/memory/S1 - Stimuli/Exp1-2-Stimuli/MIDI/Stimulus9.mid'
```

Should I indicate which columns are the factors?

Comment: provide data sample and complete error message.

Comment: Also be aware that you are dropping one column with your current slicing. Since Python is not inclusive, `datanumpy[:,0:143]` will only return columns *0 through 142*, and `datanumpy[:,144]` will select column 144, so you're ignoring column 143.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I actually want to skip column 143 as it's a second target variable to check in a second experiment.

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar I've updated the question to include the error message.

Comment: can you provide output of `df.dtypes` ? I think there are few columns in your data which are not numeric.

Comment: Yes indeed, some data is non-numerical, that's the point of my question.

Comment: Use `pd.dummies()` or `labelEncoder()` to handle non-numeric data.

Comment: It seems like labelEncoder() is very useful. I just hope the ML techniques don't average the numbers or calculate with them. You want to write this out in a full answer? I'm happy to accept then @AkshayNevrekar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As machine learning algorithm only accepts numeric data, it is very important to first convert the text data into numbers.
In python we have two ways of doing it.

1st one using `LabelEncoder()`

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

df = df.apply(LabelEncoder().fit_transform)
```

another way of doing this is using `pandas.get_dummies()`

```
import pandas as pd

df_dummies = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=categorical_columns, drop_first=True)
```

In above example `categorical_columns` is a list of categorical variables.

Answer (score 0):

SVMs cannot handle categorical data, you need to preprocess it using some technique as one hot encoding (or whatever suits your data)

Comment: I see. What about the 0 - 1 categorical data. Should I let SVM treat it as an integer? Doesn't seem correct from a statistical point of view.

Comment: How about if I want to do logistic or linear regression. In R I can mark certain variables as categorical with the factor command. Does Python have something similar?

Comment: You can use a lot of different techniques. It depends mainly on the data you are going to work with. Have a look at this post it will help you to understand the complexity of the problem and it provides a few examples that are helpful https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-feature-engineering-part-2-categorical-data-f54324193e63. Yes ,the factor command exists in Pandas library, you can convert a column using df['my-column'].astype('category').cat.codes.values

Comment: I mainly just don’t know how to use the python libraries. How do I tell it to treat it as categorical. In R I can just use the factor function.

Comment: You are using pandas in your code (almost in the sample you have provided). In the first line you read a csv file using pandas library, after this you can access to any of the columns using its column name for example df['column-name']. So you can select the column you want and apply the previous transformation.